# content provider in android initialization

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-lifecycle

I'm looking at the documentation of creating a content provider and it's stated that for the **onCreate** method, the Android system calls this method immediately after it creates your provider. and your provider is not created until a ContentResolver object tries to access it.

Despite this, when adding a content provider via the manifest, I noticed that the **onCreate** method is called immediately after the app is started, regardless of whether the provider is accessed or not.
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-creating

Is this behavior consistent/documented anywhere?

Thanks

Guy

Answer (score 0):

If you refer to API doc:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider#onCreate()
it is states that

> This method is called for all registered content providers on the application main thread at application launch time.

It is hard to say what cause your provider be initialized without referencing your code. Also, I believe the guidelines (the link you posted) is more likely out of dated compare to API doc (I reference to).
In my case, for instance, there is boot receiver, and since my app invoked by boot receiver, the content provider gets initialized as well, just like API doc said.